# Arraylist Nullpointer exception with my app

Tags: android, service, arraylist, static, nullpointerexception

heloo every one i have an application class with a static arraylist, and when i try to add an item to the arraylist i get nullpointer exception.. here is my code

```
public class SomeApp extends Application {
   public static ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
   //then i have getters and setters for ids..
   public static ArrayList<String> getIds() {
    return ids;
   }
   public static void setIds(ArrayList<String> ids) {
    SomeApp.ids = ids;
   }
}
```

now this is my service class

```
public class BpA extends Service {
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // note i created a new thread so the below code could run in..       
      SomeApp.getIds().add(UserIdname);  // i get nullpointer exception on this line
      return START_STICKY;
}
```

can some1 help me??

Comment: Can you show ther getter method too?

Comment: You've declared `ids` as `public static`, but you are accessing it from `BpA` class using `getIds()`. Paste your `getIds()` method.

Comment: ive added the getters and setters please

Comment: ive added the getters and setters please @Jens

Comment: ive added the getters and setters please @bhargavg

Comment: Can you check if `SomeApp.getIds()` returns `null`?

Comment: can you please post logcat ?

Comment: Have you added SomeApp as your Application in AndroidManifest? If not then it won't be initiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im conjuring your code, and running it under all scenarios.. so try this might work
first of all remove the getters and setters.. you can access/set ids directly by

```
SomeApp.ids
```

and set it by

```
 SomeApp.ids = (another array)
```

because it is "public static" so no need for getters and setters
2:and also check if the string is empty or not before adding to the array

```
if(userIdname != null && !userIdname.IsEmpty){
   SomeApp.ids.add(userIdname);
 }
```

and change the UserIdname to userIdname.. like i did..
possible scenarios for nullpointer exception was from your getter or String..(im guessing)

Answer (score 0):

SomeAppDid you you set you Application name in manifest file .

```
<application
        android:name="you_package.SomeApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

</application>
```

Add null checking before add UserIdname in ArrayList.

Check null in your ArrayList if it is null then recreate it.

```
public class BpA extends Service {
 @Override 
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // note i created a new thread so the below code could run in..  
if(SomeApp.getIds() != null)      
      SomeApp.getIds().add(UserIdname);  // i get nullpointer exception on this line 
      return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this directly...

```
if(UserIdname != null){
    SomeApp.ids.add(UserIdname);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i UserIdname was not null and i still had the exception..